# Restrict an AWS action unless two people confirm it. Is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am setting up a Disaster Recovery architecture for our AWS infrastructure and modelling all of it on Cloud Formation.

All the devs have power-user privileges to the infrastructure and make frequent changes depending on their needs. Naturally this messes up my Cloud Formation template.

Is there a way to restrict an action [eg add a new TCP rule in a sec group] so that must be approved by another person [me] before it takes effect ?

That way I could monitor the changes [that the devs forget to notify me about] and the Cloud Formation template would be always up to date and depicting the real thing.

*Note1*:

I have set up some event subscriptions [for RDS for starters] but I am not sure if they are the best/complete solution.

*Note2*:

The confirmation for an action could be useful for critical actions like modifying / deleting / terminating EC2 and/or RDS instances.

Answer (score 1):

Disable direct access to altering your AWS infrastructure under normal circumstances

Allow the devs to alter the cloudformation templates but have a push/go live process for them that requires approval.  For example you could set up gitolite to block changes to a "master" branch but allow changes to a "dev-changes" branch and then merge after checking it

In an emergency allow them to make the change and catch up with the templates afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the response Vorsprung, but disabling direct access for the devs is simply not an option. I would like for any viable solution to be as transparent as possible. I was wondering if there is an option provided by Amazon

Comment: I do not believe that there is a way of making the changes to an environment "pending approval" - it's not in the model.  There are two ways of dealing with the issue 1) as outlined above using change control.  There are AWS products that could do this ( maybe Codepipe or Opsworks) 2) reporting the changes via Cloudwatch or use of Cloudtrial - so the change would happen but you would be informed post hoc